# Suppressing GCC warnings on a per directory basis

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I'm dealing with a C/C++ codebase that includes some 3-rd party sources which produce large amounts of GCC warnings, which I'd like to hide. The 3-rd party code can't be modified or compiled into a library (due to shortcomings of the build system). The project is being compiled with `-Werror`.

How do I ask GCC to ignore all warnings in a part of the codebase (contained in a subdirectory), or at least make these warnings non-fatal?

I'm aware of the flag `-isystem`, but it doesn't work for me because:

- It doesn't suppress warnings in the source files, only in headers.
- It forces C linkage, so it can't be used with C++ headers.

GCC version is 4.7 or 4.8, build is `make` powered.

Comment: Is modifying the Makefiles an option? As that is where the compiler flags are set...

Comment: I can modify the top-level Makefile, but the code in question uses nested Makefiles.

Comment: You might modify the code nested Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC can't help with this, directly. The correct fix would be to tweak your build system (recursive make, perhaps).

However, you *could* write a little wrapper script that scans the parameters, and strips `-Werror` if it finds the right pattern.

E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

newargs=()
werror=true
for arg; do
   case "$arg" in
   *directory-name-i-care-about* )
       newargs=("${newargs[@]}" "$arg")
       werror=false
       ;;
   -Werror )
       ;;
   * )
       newargs=("${newargs[@]}" "$arg")
       ;;
   esac
done

if $werror; then
   newargs=("${newargs[@]}" "-Werror")
fi

exec gcc "${newargs[@]}"
```

Then, run your build with `CC=my-wrapper-script.sh`, and you're done. You could call the script `gcc` and place it earlier on the path than the real gcc, but be careful to select the correct "gcc" at the end of the script.

(I've not actually tested that script, so it might be buggy.)